# Extending Em.TextField

Tags: ember.js

I need to make a bootstrap form with 10 textfield elements.

From the bootstrap doc, I need to have this code for each textfield element:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</div>
```

Em.TextField object only manage the

```
<input type="text...
```

and I would like to minimize my handlebar form.

- What is the best solution to have the expected result with the minimum of code ?
- Is there a sample code for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new view that includes all of the required bootstrap markup and incorporates the built in `Ember.TextField` input element. The custom TextField has an added `label` property that sets the text for the form label.

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/ihotef/4/edit)

**Custom TextField:**

JS:

```
App.BootstrapTextFieldView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'bootstrapTextField',
  inputElement: null
});
```

Handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='bootstrapTextField'>
  <div class='control-group'>
    <label class="control-label" {{bindAttr for='view.inputElement.elementId'}}>{{view.label}}</label>
    <div class="controls">
      {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='view.value' viewName="inputElement"}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

**Using the new view**

You would use it similar to using the normal `Ember.TextField`:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    {{view App.BootstrapTextFieldView valueBinding='textFieldValue' labelBinding='textFieldLabel'}}
</form>
```

The only tricky part was correctly setting the `for='..."` property on the `<label>` since we need to get the auto-generated id of the `{{view Ember.TextField ...}}`. This can be done by using [the `viewName`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_view) property of the `{{view ...}}` helper. Setting `{{view App.theViewHere viewName='desiredViewName'` lets us access the instance of `Ember.TextField` we created and set the `for` property of the label to the view's id using the `{{bindAttr...}}` helper.

Comment: Tx a lot !!To make it works I have changed label='textFieldLabel' instead of labelBinding='textFieldLabel'

Comment: That's a good way to do it if you don't need to change the label.